# Can automatic deletion of "low-quality" posts be turned off?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I am not sure if automatic deletion of some "low-quality" posts (such as heavily downvoted, without reply, closed, ...) is a configurable feature  on individual stack exchange sites.

Voting is very subjective. Many "emotional" users  cast their votes (up or down or close or delete) irrationally. Voting is also like an inflectional disease, and many like to follow some lead or majority without adequate judgement. Some "low-quality" posts (many of mine) are in fact victims of malicious or ignorant downvotes and close votes with stereotyping. Some "high-quality" posts (many of mine) are in fact not worth that many upvotes, but may be because of some good replies, or being highly exposed on twitter, or having stayed for a long period, whereas I just need a proper answer.

Regardless of whether a post is truly low-quality or not,  every post (except extreme cases, such as Unix & Linux unrelated, or offensive posts) deserves their existences, and  visibility  to the public. Their existence have values. Duplicates  can help us to recognize the different appearances of the same or related problems. Victim posts will still have chances to be re-recognized. The posts of a user can be kept tracked of by themselves or others for reducing the possibility of making the same mistakes or asking the same questions.

In the meantime, I am not sure if SE sites might have some technological difficulty of keeping every post's existence and visibility, but I just can't imagine there is one (limitation on storage, querying processing, ...).

Thanks.

Comment: " there might be some technology difficulty of keeping every post's existence and visibility..." It's called a *blog*.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry, but this is a network-wide feature, not something that can be configured for each site. That said, this statement is really problematic:

> Regardless of whether a post is truly low-quality or not, every post deserves their existence, and visibility to the public.

I am afraid that if that's the way you feel, then Stack Exchange is not a good fit. Deleting low quality posts is essential to the way these sites work. If that is really something that bothers you, then I can only recommend that you find another site that doesn't have SE's strict rules about content.